# Display JSON Properties in Kusto Query - specific Subnets

Tags: json, azure, dashboard, kql

Hello i have a little problem i couldn't find an answer i could understand anywhere.

i am about to make a dashboard in azure by using Azure Resource Graph Explorer and their Kusto query language, i would like to display how many Subnets there is i the subscription.

but when i try to seperate and show the subnets in it only show me either the amount of Vnets there is or it show one line of subnets and not how many.

i've tried to project the subnets with following code but dont know what to write to show a single line with two rows with the name "subnets" and how many of them.

**Summary:** is that; i want to write a Kusto query that i can pin to dashboard that shows how many subnets there is.

Code i tried to write:

```
resources
| project properties.subnets
```

output is:
**properties_subnets**

```
null
[{"type":"Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets","properties":{"provisioningState":"Succeeded", etc. etc. etc. 






{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "virtualNetworks_Vnet_name": {
            "defaultValue": "Vnet",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
            "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
            "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworks_Vnet_name')]",
            "location": "westeurope",
            "properties": {
                "addressSpace": {
                    "addressPrefixes": [
                        "10.0.0.0/16"
                    ]
                },
                "subnets": [
                    {
                        "name": "default",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
                            "delegations": [],
                            "privateEndpointNetworkPolicies": "Enabled",
                            "privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies": "Enabled"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "default2",
                        "properties": {
                            "addressPrefix": "10.0.1.0/24",
                            "serviceEndpoints": [],
                            "delegations": [],
                            "privateEndpointNetworkPolicies": "Enabled",
                            "privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies": "Enabled"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "virtualNetworkPeerings": [],
                "enableDdosProtection": false,
                "enableVmProtection": false
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
            "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworks_Vnet_name'), '/default')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworks_Vnet_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
                "delegations": [],
                "privateEndpointNetworkPolicies": "Enabled",
                "privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies": "Enabled"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
            "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworks_Vnet_name'), '/default2')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworks_Vnet_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "addressPrefix": "10.0.1.0/24",
                "serviceEndpoints": [],
                "delegations": [],
                "privateEndpointNetworkPolicies": "Enabled",
                "privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies": "Enabled"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: So is the output you want to display *included* in your json output. or do you need to find another query?

Comment: the subnets is a property (child item) of a Virtual network and i would like to write a query that picks only the subnets and show how many there are.

If that makes sense

Comment: Which field do you want to pick out from your received json?

Comment: I have updated my question to include my Virtual network in the bottom of the question and a JSON - what i then want is to query out the amount of Subnets there is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
resources 
| where type=~"Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks" 
| project array_length(properties.subnets)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and for the fast response i got it to work, and it looks like this;

resources
| where type=~"Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"
| project ["Number of Subnets"]=array_length(properties.subnets)
| top 15 by ["Number of Subnets"] desc

Comment: You can probably write it even shorter, like `resources | where type=~"Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks" | project array_length(properties.subnets)`. Or is that not true?